# How to scroll to a desired location in a view?

Tags: android, button, view, scrollview

Since my ScrollView is very long, and users need to scroll down for a long time to arrive to the desired TableLayout, I would like to ask whether there are functions in a way that if I design a button such that when it was pressed, it will automatically scroll down itself to the desired TableLayout location?

I do not know what is this named in technical term. Could somebody tell me how to achieve it? Would there be examples of codes? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6831790/786337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [Can I scroll a ScrollView programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438061/can-i-scroll-a-scrollview-programmatically-in-android)

In your activity:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setONClickListener(new Button.OnCLickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myScrollView.scrollTo(0, y_index);
    }
});
```