# How to scroll ScrollView to certain position in the text

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I have a ScrollView with a TextView inside it, and I'd like to scroll it to a certain paragraph, just like anchors in HTML (e.g page.html#paragraph_id).

Does anybody know a way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not smart at HTML, If you want to scroll the scrollview programmatically, Can achieve by following  ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrl);
sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getBottom());
or

sv.scrollTo(5, 10);

Answer (score 1):

Try using `scrollTo` method [More Info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29)

check with follow code

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);//my text view
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);//my scrollview
String log ="a Very long text";
tv.setText(log);

sv.post(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        sv.scrollTo(0, "value till you want to scroll");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Really a very intresting question. I am also tyring to do so.
        What I have done is an idea to map textview - lines to scrollview coordinates. 
        what you can do is get the device-display size - in pixels. 
        and a line height of the textview by- textview.getLineheight();  and calculate the line 
        coordinates and map it to the scrollview
        As I said I am also trying to do this. I am currently working on the same.
        If I find some code working I will let you know.

[image]

Its lot of work to do because android os does not provide such kind of scroll you (or I) want 
**OR you can have textview for each line** and use this code 
`mScrollView.scrollTo(0, your_text_view_with_the_line.getBottom());`

Comment: Why bother so much? Just split it into different TextViews and use the above solution...

Comment: @Erez.info Making so much objects will consume more heap. So... And I have specified the you can use the one textview per line. but suppose you have 500 lines. then this is serius issue

Comment: You're right, but in my case there is only 10 paragraphs, so this soultion is excellent. Anyway, I'd like to see your code when you're finished

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438061/can-i-scroll-a-scrollview-programmatically-in-android)?

Imagine you have a TextView or similar element (in your case your html#paragraph_1), then you could get the Top Position of this element by:

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_your_text_view);
int position = yourTextView.getTop(); // you could also call yourTextView.getBottom()
```

After that you could scroll to your position (you could put this code snippet in your onClick() method or similar, to jump to this position when clicking on a link or button):

```
ScrollView sc = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);

sc.post(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
        sc.scrollTo(0, position); // these are your x and y coordinates
    }
});
```

Note: I expected `yourTextView` to be in the ScrollView layout.

Hope this helps you getting started.