# ScrollView auto scroll after particular field in android

Tags: android, scrollview

This code helps me to auto scrolling on click function but when the edit text4 is clicked it is scrolled up only one field above. I want that field to go to the top of the screen. I used scroll up, scroll by, scroll To, everything but all gives the same result. Would you please help.

---

```
package com.example.scrollview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ScrollView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{
EditText edtText4,edtText8;
ScrollView scrollView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scv);

    edtText4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    edtText8 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);  

    edtText4.setOnTouchListener(selectedFieldTouchListener);
    edtText8.setOnTouchListener(selectedFieldTouchListener);

}
private OnTouchListener selectedFieldTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int top1 = 0;
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.editText4:
            top1 = edtText4.getTop();  
            break;
        case R.id.editText8:
            top1 = edtText8.getTop();
            break;
        }
        final int top = top1;
        scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {//must be in postDelayed otherwise wont work

            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, edtText4.getTop());
            }
        }, 100);

        return false;
    }
};
```

}

---

Comment: You can find answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6438061/3640637

Comment: I tried that code but there is no change, while scrolling only it goes up or down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that the `EditTexts` are direct children of the `ScrollView`

```
private OnTouchListener selectedFieldTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int top1 = 0;
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.editText4:
                top1 = edtText4.getTop();
                break;
            case R.id.editText8:
                top1 = edtText8.getTop();
                break;
            }
            final int top = top1;
            scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {//must be in postDelayed otherwise wont work

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    scrollView.scrollTo(0, top);
                }
            }, 100);

            return false;
        }
    };
```

and then add the `Touch Listener` to your `EditTexts`

```
    edtText4.setOnTouchListener(selectedFieldTouchListener);
    edtText8.setOnTouchListener(selectedFieldTouchListener);
```

Comment: what will you do if he use nex key from the keyboard??!! you need to consider that too.

Comment: for that you can add an onFocusChangeListener

Comment: I'm getting NullPointerException