# Can I scroll ScrollView programmatically to a specific position?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scrollview

Is there any way to scroll a `ScrollView` programmatically to a certain position?

I have created a `RelativeLayout` and it has a `ScrollView` and a child `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView`.
I used this code for Scrolling down. but it Scroll very less

```
        sv0.post(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 

            //sv0.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            sv0.scrollTo(1000, 1000);
        } 
});
```

Is there any way to scroll to specific location programmatically?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! When typing in a question a list of possible questions already asked appears, be sure to look at them.

Comment: In that duplicate, the best answer is possibly not the accepted one, be sure to scroll to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8684666/360211

Comment: thank you. but i seen this before. and this question does not explain how to scroll to specific position.

Comment: @weston: i used this code        sv0.post(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
             
             //sv0.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
             sv0.scrollTo(1000, 1000);
            } 
    }); but it just scroll down very less.

Comment: You should put what you have tried in the question when you ask it. It saves people suggesting stuff you have tried/duplicates and shows effort on your part. Edit the question to put the code in. Code looks horrible in comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561353/programmatically-scroll-to-a-specific-position-in-an-android-listview

Comment: I solved this myself. you can use         final ScrollView sv0=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.Scrollbar1);

        sv0.post(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
             sv0.smoothScrollBy(0, 12200);

            } 
    }); to go to down in layout:)