# Failed to return to my Activity after taking a picture with the camera on my device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Well you will see friends, I am developing a project which involves taking 4 pictures from the camera to my device , the problem is when I'm taking pictures and when you go to capture some of them to return to my activity sends me this error.

```
04-08 21:44:39.493 28084-28084/com.example.user.activofijo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.user.activofijo, PID: 28084
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.activofijo/com.example.user.activofijo.AgregarActivo}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2480)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4293)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1383)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5725)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1030)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.example.user.activofijo.AgregarActivo.selectionspinner(AgregarActivo.java:1174)
                                                                         at com.example.user.activofijo.AgregarActivo.onCreate(AgregarActivo.java:151)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6018)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2480) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4293) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1383) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5725) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1030) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
04-08 21:44:39.493 840-3251/? E/ActivityManager: App crashed! Process: com.example.user.activofijo
```

So indicates the error is on the part of the spinner.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
```

I have 4 spinners in the activity where each load data received from a server just put the code where stated .

```
public class AgregarActivo extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
Spinner spinner_oficina;
Spinner spinner_departamento;
Spinner spinner_personal;
Spinner spinner_categoria;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agregar_activo);

 selectionspinner();

}
public void selectionspinner(){
    spinner_oficina = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_oficina);
    spinner_departamento = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_departamento);
    spinner_personal = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_personal);
    spinner_categoria = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_categoria);

    spinner_oficina.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            int id_oficinapost = arrayoficinas.get(pos).getIdOficina();
            String res1 = String.valueOf(id_oficinapost);
            tvO.setText(res1);

            spinnerdepartamento(res1);

        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    spinner_departamento.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            int id_departamento = arraydepartamentos.get(pos).getIdDepartamento();
            String res2 = String.valueOf(id_departamento);
            tvD.setText(res2);
            spinnerpersonal(res2);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    spinner_personal.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            Integer id_personalpost = arraypersonal.get(pos).getIdpersonal();
            String res3 = String.valueOf(id_personalpost);
            tvP.setText(res3);
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    spinner_categoria.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            int id_categoriapost = arraycategorias.get(pos).getIdcategoria();
            String res4 = String.valueOf(id_categoriapost);
            tvC.setText(res4);

        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}
}
```

Code picture.

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    try {
        //------------------CÓDIGO DE BARRAS------------------------
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //Quiere decir que se obtuvo resultado pro lo tanto:
            //Desplegamos en pantalla el contenido del código de barra scaneado
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            contentTxt.setText(scanContent);
            //Desplegamos en pantalla el nombre del formato del código de barra scaneado
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
            formatTxt.setText(scanFormat);
            capturas_scan = capturas_scan + 1;
        }
        if (scanningResult == null) {
            //Quiere decir que NO se obtuvo resultado

            if (capturas_scan == 1) {
                capturas_scan = capturas_scan - 1;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No se ha recibido datos del scaneo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            } else {
                if(contentTxt.getText().equals("")) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "No se ha recibido datos del scaneo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        }

        //FOTOGRAFIA
        if (capturas_scan == 0) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            int id = R.layout.layout_right;
            LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(id, null, false);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            params.topMargin = 100;
            relativeLayout.setPadding(5, 3, 5, 3);
            //relativeLayout.setPadding(5, 3, 5, 3);
            relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            /**
             * Se revisa si la imagen viene de la c‡mara (TAKE_PICTURE) o de la galer’a (SELECT_PICTURE)
             */

            if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
                /**
                 * Si se reciben datos en el intent tenemos una vista previa (thumbnail)
                 */
                if (data != null) {
                    /**
                     * En el caso de una vista previa, obtenemos el extra ÒdataÓ del intent y
                     * lo mostramos en el ImageView
                     */
                    try {

                        if (data.hasExtra("data")) {
                            iv = (ImageView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
                            iv.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data.getParcelableExtra("data"));
                            BitmapDrawable estirable = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
                            Bitmap bitmap = estirable.getBitmap();
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, bos);
                            byte[] bb = bos.toByteArray();
                            image = Base64.encodeToString(bb, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                            if (capturas == 0) {
                                v.add(0, image);
                            } else
                                v.add(capturas, image);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hubo un error" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    /**
                     * De lo contrario es una imagen completa
                     */
                } else {
                    /**
                     * A partir del nombre del archivo ya definido lo buscamos y creamos el bitmap
                     * para el ImageView
                     */
                    iv = (ImageView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(name));
                    /**
                     * Para guardar la imagen en la galer’a, utilizamos una conexi—n a un MediaScanner
                     */
                    new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                        private MediaScannerConnection msc = null;

                        {
                            msc = new MediaScannerConnection(getApplicationContext(), this);
                            msc.connect();
                        }

                        public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                            msc.scanFile(name, null);
                        }

                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            msc.disconnect();
                        }
                    };
                }
                /**
                 * Recibimos el URI de la imagen y construimos un Bitmap a partir de un stream de Bytes
                 */
                capturas = capturas + 1;
            } else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                InputStream is;
                try {
                    is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                }

            }
            layout.addView(relativeLayout);

            //scroll to last element
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438061/can-i-scroll-a-scrollview-programmatically-in-android

            scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                }
            });
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ha habido un error"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.user.activofijo.AgregarActivo">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/textViewInfoUsuario" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewResId"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/scan_button"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/barras"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/scan_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:hint="@string/numero_serie"
                   />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/info_cam"
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Obtener"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:id="@+id/btnPic"
                    android:src="@drawable/camara"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:onClick="addRight" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left">

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonsLayout"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        />
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/oficina"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textViewImagen" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_oficina"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/texto_oficina"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/texto_oficina"
                android:layout_below="@+id/texto_oficina"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvOficina"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/departamento"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner_departamento"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvDepartamento"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/encargado_activo"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner_personal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvPersonal"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scan_format"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/scan_button"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/categoria"
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner_categoria"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
               />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvCategoria"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >




            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: post your xml and camara activity code.

Comment: do you have any code on your onResume or onStart?

Comment: i guess one of the spinner is inflated with wrong id and thus it wud help if u post ur xml code of this activity

Comment: I do not use onResume and onStart in my code

Comment: just a wild guess but worth a try. add "if(savedInstanceState != null) return;" just above selectionspinner(); in onCreate and see if it helps

Comment: thank you very much now seems to work smoothly and does not mark the same problem :D

Comment: Although I now appears another problem lol @Pooya

Comment: @CarlosHernández what is the problem?

Comment: this http://subefotos.com/ver/?ecb17f2aabfa66291a8d943adb01eed4o.jpg#codigos

Answer (score -1):

It cause may be your Spinner cannot find in your **activity_agregar_activo** layout file.

Please check the layout file, and set actual id to **findViewById(___)**