# Automatic scroll CardView after expanding

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, scroll

​I am developing an Android application that has a ListView containing CardViews populated using a custom ArrayAdapter .

The CardViews have an expandable area that becomes visible on click by sliding downward .​​

However when i view the last CardView that is visible on the screen i can only see the non-expandable part of the CardView i.e. the expandable can only be viewed if i scroll downward myself.

I have seen this type of feature before where the layout automatically adjusts by scrolling downward to include the expandable part .

I have not been able to implement this myself .

How can i achieve this functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using scrollview as wrapper over your content inside CardView. You can use

```
mScrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
         mScrollView.scrollTo(0, mScrollView.getBottom());
    } 
});
```

or

```
mScrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
         mScrollView.fullScroll(mScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    } 
});
```

above two codes are from question [Can I scroll a ScrollView programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438061)

also try

```
scrollView.scrollTo(0, TextView.getBottom());
```

where textview is at bottom of your cardview

else you can try using

```
yourview.fullscroll(yourview.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

if thats even possible

Comment: I have used a list view of card views so if i use "scrollview as wrapper over my content inside CardView" it doesnt have any influence over the scroll of activity .