# Android slide up bottom sheet from dragging main content layout

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I use persistent `bottom sheet` view in `coordinatorLayout`. my layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- main content -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- i need Dragging this layout to slide up bottom sheet -->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- persistent bottom sheet -->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="70dp">

        <!-- content bottom sheet (recyclerview or ...) -->

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and register bottom sheet view:

```
BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;
View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet);
bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
```

now, in addition to slide through bottom `R.id.bottomSheet`, I also need dragging main content `R.id.mainContentLayout` to slide up bottomSheet.

How to add this feature?

[image]

Comment: You want your content to slide up WITH the bottom sheet, right?

Comment: @Vucko No. only need slide up bottomSheet from main content.when i sliding up on content, bottom sheet slide up.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a `nested scroll view` for such behavior? Because to me, it looks like you could have a layout with 2 fragments one below the other, with a small View in between. You can make the scroller disable for a while and when the user clicks the View, you can make the screen scroll [programmically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8684666/7500651)

Comment: @anshsachdeva no i dont need `nestedScrollView`. Because my `recyclerView` have large rows with header. i just need sliding from main content

Comment: @Vucko can you help me? for (content to slide up WITH the bottom sheet) i can use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"`, but behavior is lag and bug.

Comment: bottomSheet height was match_parent, make it wrap.. try once..

Comment: @anshsachdeva This is not the answer to my question. Pay attention to my question